# Regular expression for month date and day (dd mmmm and day)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

How should I write a regular expression for checking the string `'Saturday 26 October'` in JavaScript? I have tried to get the day using this regex:

```
/^(Sunday(,(?=.)|$))?(Monday(,(?=.)|$))?(Tuesday(,(?=.)|$))?(Wednesday(,(?=.)|$))?(Thursday(,(?=.)|$))?(Friday(,(?=.)|$))?(Saturday)$/
```

but I'm not sure how should I write that for both the date and the month.

Comment: Can you please specify the general inputs that you want to match maybe a few examples of sample input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is an API built on JavaScript. There's no such thing as jQuery REGEX, therefore.

Your current REGEX is a little insane - try this:

```
/^(Mon|Tues|Wednes|Thurs|Fri|Satur|Sun)day \d\d? ((Jan|Febr)uary|March|April|May|Ju(ne|ly)|August|(Septem|Octo|Novem|Decem)ber)$/
```

Comment: I really like how you cut down on the size by using the common suffixes.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't really specified which bits of the date can vary, so I'm assuming everything.
Here's the regex:

```
(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)[ -/](\d{1,2})[ -/](January|Feburary|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/W-fDU8GznNBwQGPh)